# F# and migrations using Entity Framework Core

Tags: f#, entity-framework-core

Hi i have a question,

Using entity framework core in c# I am able to do migration of db if it does not exits on startup and it looks fairly easy (using this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/)

```
 db.Database.Migrate();
```

Where db is context.

So in f# where context looks like:

module GeneralContext

```
open Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
open DataAccess.Model.Cabin
open DataAccess.TypeProviders.DatabaseSettings

type GeneralContext() = 
    inherit DbContext()

    override this.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder : DbContextOptionsBuilder) =  

        let connetionString = DatabaseSettings.GetDbConfiguration
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connetionString) |> ignore

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable Cabins : DbSet<Cabin>

    member public this.Cabin
        with get() = this.Cabins
        and set cabin = this.Cabins <- cabin
```

I try:

```
let Migrate =

   use context = new GeneralContext()
   context.Database.Migrate()
```

But I am getting message that field constructor migrate is not defined. I checked namespaces comparing c# and f# projects for entity framework core facade and they are the same,

I am using in mu nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package explicitly.